# Looking for a youtube animation about a cyborg

Tags: story-identification, animation

I'm looking for an animation I saw on Youtube. The main character was a cyborg with blue hair and a gaskmask that fought with pistols and grenades. The animation starts with the main character jumping into a cyberpunk city. Eventually he ends up fighting a giant robot scorpion.

Comment: When did you see that animation? Was is like anime or real action movie? Could it be video from some gameplay, ending with the fight with some scorpio-boss? Could it be that your cyborg is just a human looking like cyborg?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi I saw the animation more then 10 years ago 07-11. It was just an action short film animated in 3d. I'm almost sure that it wasn't part of a video game or any other property. I can't be sure on wether the main character was a cyborg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, must be that one [Azureus Rising - Proof of Concept Teaser Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agk2svo7svI)

MC (human):

[image]

Pistols:

[image]

Grenade:

[image]

Scorpio:

[image]

(search query: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=3d+animation+fight+with+scrorpion)